# PHP - Why does parse_url() return false for /search/publication_year:2019?

Tags: php, url

In PHP 7.4.3 parsing the following URL using `parse_url()` returns `false`:

`/search/publication_year:2019`

In the documentation it says that:

> On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return false.

Seems like it considers URLs that include `:` followed by a number to be "seriously malformed".

Any ideas how to get around this issue ?

Comment: This function may not give correct results for relative URLs. see notes of [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse_url() sometimes gives unreliable results when not passing in a full URL - try adding the domain and protocol - you'll see in my examples below that if I put http://www.google.com/ in the expected response comes back.

There was also a bug in php 5.4 that incorrectly returned false when a colon was present.

See:
https://www.tehplayground.com/okoFSmISFCKNYaav

For some example output from parse_url

Comment: You may find this library which uses reg-ex when parse_url returns NULL handy if you aren't able to work around this issue:

https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/uri